# What's the story behind the revision history of Go?

Tags: go, mercurial

I noticed that the first 4 revisions `f6182e5abf5e`, `b66d0bf8da3e`, `ac3363d7e788`, `172d32922e72` of the Go source are all from long before Golang was even proposed, [the oldest being from 1972](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/7d7c6a97f815e9279d08cfaea7d5efb5e90695a8).  They are also all credited to Brian Kernighan of AWK-ward fame.  They seem to be `hello, world` implementations in C. Is this an easter-egg or is there some practical purpose?

Comment: Go's history seems to have been altered somehow. As of November 7, 2017, the first 4 commits are listed as [`7d7c6a9`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/7d7c6a9), [`0bb0b61`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/0bb0b61), [`0744ac9`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/0744ac9), [`d82b11e`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d82b11e)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That [thread](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/rCWlhvo9bLM) mentions:

> Homage, Easter egg, inside joke, take your pick :).  Notice the authors of the commits in question too

Said thread references [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/7d7c6a97f815e9279d08cfaea7d5efb5e90695a8) as the starting point, but also points out to the [actual first commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/18c5b488a3b2e218c0e0cf2a7d4820d9da93a554) of the Golang project, with the [first revision of the Go spec](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/18c5b488a3b2e218c0e0cf2a7d4820d9da93a554/doc/go_spec).

The (alleged) "author" of the four first commits is [Brian Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernighan).
[Rob Pike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Pike) has worked with Brian in the 1980's, at [Bell Labs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Labs), so this can be viewed as a reference to his professional origin.

The idea of this Easter egg is to illustrate an evolution of an `Hello World` program in C:

(See more with this recent GopherCon April 2014 talk [**`hellogophers.slide` - Rob Pike**](http://talks.golang.org/2014/hellogophers.slide))

---

### Hello, World

```c
hg log -r 0:4
changeset:   0:f6182e5abf5e
user:        Brian Kernighan <bwk>
date:        Tue Jul 18 19:05:45 1972 -0500
summary:     hello, world

$ hg update -r 0
$ cat src/pkg/debug/macho/testdata/hello.b

main( ) {
    extrn a, b, c;
    putchar(a); putchar(b); putchar(c); putchar('!*n');
}
a 'hell';
b 'o, w';
c 'orld';
```

---

### Convert to C

```c
changeset:   1:b66d0bf8da3e
user:        Brian Kernighan <bwk>
date:        Sun Jan 20 01:02:03 1974 -0400
summary:     convert to C

$ hg update -r 1
$ cat src/pkg/debug/macho/testdata/hello.c

main() {
    printf("hello, world");
}
```

---

### Convert to Draft-Proposed ANSI C

```c
changeset:   2:ac3363d7e788
user:        Brian Kernighan <research!bwk>
date:        Fri Apr 01 02:02:04 1988 -0500
summary:     convert to Draft-Proposed ANSI C

$ hg update -r 2
$ cat src/pkg/debug/macho/testdata/hello.c

#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

---

### Last-minute fix: convert to ANSI C

```c
changeset:   3:172d32922e72
user:        Brian Kernighan <bwk@research.att.com>
date:        Fri Apr 01 02:03:04 1988 -0500
summary:     last-minute fix: convert to ANSI C

$ hg update -r 3
cat src/pkg/debug/macho/testdata/hello.c


#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Go spec starting point

```c
changeset:   4:4e9a5b095532
user:        Robert Griesemer <gri@golang.org>
date:        Sun Mar 02 20:47:34 2008 -0800
summary:     Go spec starting point.
```

Comment: Also top comment on the reddit page for that language: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/a3184/go_an_experimental_language_from_google/

Comment: [Rob Pike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Pike) work with [Brian Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernighan) at [Bell Labs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Labs) in the 1980's. So it is a reference to his professional origin.

Comment: Love Go, this question and also the answer but is this not considered off-topic for SO?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij No, it involves a programming language and code, it is as such relevant for Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok my bad. Fun fact the file still exists at a different location https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/debug/macho/testdata/hello.c

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Yes, as part of https://docs.google.com/document/d/12w7ksAXmo3sF1EWlbAp4adrm1kJoe_8WIFlaZshIHWM/edit: getting rid of the `pkg` folder in `src/`.